# Foundry Workshop or Quiver - Period-bucket editable by user in view mode, is it possible?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is it possible in Workshop or Quiver to expose an bar chart with Timeline X-axis where **time-bucket (day, week, month, year, ...)** is changeable by user (in reading mode).

> I want to move from Slate to Workshop/Quiver applications without loosing this feature.

Comment: Solved, I Will publish my solution soon.